# Android : get id of listview row when button clicked

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

i have a listview that contains relative views on each list item that are populated by a database and contains two buttons. 
when one of the buttons in the list view item is pressed i need to get the id of that row in the list view. in other words i am trying to find the same thing as the last argument in the onItemClick methos for the onItemClickListener(), which would return a click for the entire item. however i am just listening for the button in the listview item so i am unable to use onItemClickListener().

i have this method being called when i click the button

```
public void plusClick(View v) 
    {

        //get the row the clicked button is in
        RelativeLayout vwParentRow = (RelativeLayout)v.getParent();

        //i need to get the id of this RelativeLayout item in the list view

        TextView child = (TextView)vwParentRow.getChildAt(2);
        Button btnChild = (Button)vwParentRow.getChildAt(1);


        int c = Color.CYAN;


        vwParentRow.setBackgroundColor(c); 
        vwParentRow.refreshDrawableState();       
    }
```

it need to find the id of the relative layout which i can pass ass arg for

```
public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                    where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

to create a new cursor contiain the data in this listview item

Comment: How do you set the `OnClickListener` for each button?

Comment: "to create a new cursor contiain the data in this listview item"...umm...why do you need a new cursor? Are you not using `CursorAdapter`? If not, I strongly suggest that you do. It sounds like you are trying to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: the buttons are currently set with the xml android:onClick="plusClick"

Comment: @sam: easiest solution would be to tag the button with the appropriate data (i.e. the id, if that's all you're interested in). Alternatively, set the `OnClickListener` yourself. You can then either supply the data as extra parameter(s) in i.e. the constructor, or implement the listener as an anonymous class, directly referencing the relevant data.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
private OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position,
                long id) {  
                // write your logic here        
                // position starts from 0
                // id starts from 1

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

when you set onclicklistener for your button you can set tag for it(tag can be id of row), and then when you click on button get it's tag. (of course if you use custom adapter)

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of adapter, in getView method you have to declare your event

There is an example:

```
holder.hMention.setOnClickListener(new VerTweet(mention));
```

and...

```
public class VerTweet implements View.OnClickListener 
{

    Mention mention;

    public VerTweet ( Mention mention) {
        this.mention = mention;
    }

    public void onClick( View view ){

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        //Le ponemos la variable parametro con el contenido test
        bundle.putInt("idTrack", mention.getIdTrack());
        bundle.putString("Gifo", mention.getGifo());
        bundle.putString("From", mention.getFromUser());
        bundle.putString("Date", mention.getDateMentions());
        bundle.putString("Text", mention.getText());
        bundle.putLong("Status", mention.getLastId());
        Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), Tweet.class);
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        getContext().startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

https://github.com/m-alcu/SkoltiAlert/blob/master/src/com/alcubier/skoltialert/mentions/GDMentionsList.java